# Emacs Configuration

Tags: emacs, clojure

I am trying to get started with Emacs/Clojure. What is the proper way to install emacs extensions. I am trying to install the the following plugin:

https://bitbucket.org/kotarak/vimclojure

I have placed it in ~/.emacs/plugins but it does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general there is quite some amical animosity between the Vi users and the Emacs users.

I am quite certain that trying to make a Vim plugin work in Emacs is quite impossible.

For emacs use I suggest you checkout clojurebox if you 're on windows as it contains a preconfigured emacs environment.

On Unix like environments emacs is more native and you can use SLIME which is usually available as a OS package or as a separate download for e.g. Aquamacs.

In combination with Leiningen : https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/emacs-integration

you have also a nice environemnet.

Good luck and happy hacking

Answer (score 2):

That is a Vim plugin. It cannot be expected to work with Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the horse's mouth: [Getting Started with Emacs](http://dev.clojure.org/display/doc/Getting+Started+with+Emacs)

Comment: That page still recommends swank-clojure which is almost obsolete now. Better start with clojure-mode and nrepl.el.  You can get both from http://marmalade-repo.org/ (see the instructions there).

Answer (score 1):

Instructions for ubuntu here (but they go over to any unix or mac):

http://www.learningclojure.com/2010/08/clojure-emacs-swank-slime-maven-maven.html